# Alterar coluna existente para Identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Tendo uma entidade onde a chave primeira é um inteiro e a mesma está definida para não ser um `Identity`

```
public class Teste
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Ao tentar alterar a chave primaria para um `Identity`, o `migrations` não está gerado o script corretamente.

```
public class Teste
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

O `migrations` até está correto

```
public partial class M2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Testes");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Testes", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Testes", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Testes");
        AlterColumn("dbo.Testes", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Testes", "Id");
    }
}
```

No entanto o script para o banco não está correto.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Testes] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Testes]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Testes] ALTER COLUMN [Id] [int] NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Testes] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Testes] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201708071357537_M2', N'ConsoleApp1.Migrations.Configuration',  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
```

Estaria faltando o `alter column` para transformar o `id` em uma coluna identidade.

Comment: Você tentou alterar apagando o atributo ou modificando ele?

Comment: Não existe a possibilidade de fazer isso, pois a tabela real já tem dados e outros relacionamentos.

Comment: Modificando, você quer dizer renomeando?

Comment: Modificando é alterando o atributo de `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` para **`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`**.

Comment: Então, é o que estou tentando fazer, mas para Identity

Comment: Isso, foi identity que eu quis dizer.

Comment: [Você não pode alterar as colunas existentes para identidade.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049305/2740371)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza interessante, parece que tem também esse **ALTER TABLE...SWITCH** que eu nunca tinha ouvido falar, mas aparentemente com ele você pula a etapa de fazer a carga de dados com o INSERT SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível mudar uma coluna existente para `Identity` no SQL Server, por isso o EF6 acaba *ignorando* o `identity: true` do migration, o que pra mim é errado, deveria dar um erro te avisando que ele não consegue gerar um script por esse e aquele motivo.

Se a tabela é nova e não contém dados, é mais fácil "comentar" o `DbSet`:

```
// public DbSet<Teste> Testes {get; set;}
```

Daí ao gerar o migrations, ele vai entender que deve excluir a tabela:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropTable("dbo.Testes");
}
```

Depois "descomente" o `DbSet` e gere outro migrations:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Testes",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Nome = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);          
}
```

---

Se é uma tabela que já contém dados e você precisa manter o ID, sugiro que você crie uma nova tabela (ex: `Testes_Temp`) com o `Id` já sendo **Identity**, use esse comando para habilitar a inclusão de valores no campo Id:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Testes_Temp ON
```

Daí você terá que fazer uma carga de dados (Insert com Select), algo assim:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Testes_Temp ( Id, Nome )
SELECT  Id, Nome
FROM dbo.Testes
```

Daí você desabilita o `IDENTITY_INSERT`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Testes_Temp OFF
```

Exclui a tabela antiga e renomeia a nova.

Comment: que trampo, não dar para mudar o  IDENTITY direto na tabela do banco ? mesma que ela já tenha dados :)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não é possível :( nem com query direto (ex: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Testes] ALTER COLUMN [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY`) e nem pelo **Designer** do SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Nessas situações eu tenho gerado o script das alterações pelo management studio, que resumidamente o que ele faz é o que você colocou na sua resposta. E também adiciono o script gerado pelo SSMS e adiciona uma migrations igual.

Comment: @Alisson é possível sim você fazer pelo SSMS a alteração, mas antes de que desabilitar a opção que previne o recriar tabelas

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas eu tentei aqui desabilitar, e mesmo assim não foi possível alterar para Identity. Estou utilizando SQL Server 2008 com o SSMS 2014. Você usa qual versão? Pode ser que tenham habilitado isso em versões mais novas (não fui pesquisar), mas nessa versão que estou utilizando eu não consigo alterar nem pelo SSMS.